# Raspberry Pi Zero WH dead

Tags: power, pi-zero-w

I have problem with my Raspberry Pi Zero. When powering on with sd card inserted nothing happens, no LED is flashing. The os on the sd card is working on another raspberry pi.

The problem occured after I had tried connecting Lipo 3S battery through step-down converter (5V) to power rpi. The green led was flashing irregulary and after a while it went out.

I used this one [Step-down converter](https://www.banggood.com/pl/DC-DC-9V12V24V28V-To-5V-3A-Step-Down-Power-Supply-Module-Cellphone-Car-Charger-USB-Buck-Regulator-p-1215392.html?gmcCountry=PL&currency=PLN&createTmp=1&utm_source=googleshopping&utm_medium=cpc_bgs&utm_content=lijing&utm_campaign=pla-pl-pc-rm-purchase-all-0821&gclid=Cj0KCQjw9tbzBRDVARIsAMBplx_ZKEFID0xQdqwOrSB3Q3YrtnVbmRRVzaoo6nBATakf1oRGLdo2TfgaAlvQEALw_wcB&cur_warehouse=CN) with USB cable to connect converter to rpi and no GPIO were used.

Anyone has an idea what could go wrong? Is there any chance to repair my rpi or should I get a new one?

I have noticed that when I check voltage on GPIO pins, 5v gives me 5v and 3v3 only 1,6v.

Comment: since you said nothing about the power supply that you are using, i suspect that you have a bad power supply

Comment: After this issue with step-down converter, I've tried running it with original rpi power supply. Raspberry Pi 3 works fine with this power supply, so I believe that's ok.

Comment: Please follow the [The Boot Problems Sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151) to narrow down the problem.